# Is this patent valid in México?

Tags: patent-infringement, design-patent, intellectual-property, usd705533

In reference to the patent: [USD 705,533 S](https://www.google.com/patents/USD705533)

Is this design patent valid worldwide? I've been selling a similar product (different in design, materials and size) for years without knowing about this, I'm in México, I don't pretend to export or claim rights over the product I make, just selling it for college funding purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Patents are only valid in the country they are issued.  There is no such thing as a worldwide patent.  This particular patent is a US Design patent.  As such, this patent cannot be enforced in Mexico (or anywhere outside of the US).  The only concern would be whether there is a counterpart patent issued in Mexico.